# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy in react & C# program

Tags: c#, reactjs, performance, lighthouse

I want to fix lighthouse problem "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy 5 resources found". There are 3 fonts, 1 svg and js bundle files that provoking this. I tried adding headers on server and using it on client side, but nothing is changed.
My C# code

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
    }
});
```

My react proxy setup

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:7206',
      changeOrigin: true,
      onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        if (
          req.url.match(/\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/)
        ) {
          proxyRes.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=31536000'
        }
      },
    })
  )
}
```

Tried to see what headers are in network tab devtools but there no such header I wrote

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front of the app? If so could you try doing it there?  NGINX and Apache make it pretty simple.  Also, did you try another header/value combination?  Maybe the app doesn't allow appending `cache-control` as a header name because it is considered reserved.

Comment: Gerg, I don't have load balancer. Tried rename it to cache-control, it doesn't work